# In angular 1.x are interceptors always factories?

Tags: angularjs, service, interceptor

I'm trying to wrap my head around interceptors, I still can't figure them out. Can someone explain a tad more for me about if they are a service, a config, etc?

Comment: answer is in the [$http docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http). Whole section on interceptors. Lots of tutorials around for this topic lso

Answer (score 2):

Interceptors can be either a named factory or an anonymous factory.

```
app.config(function ($httpProvider) {

    //register the interceptor factory    
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');


    // alternatively, register the interceptor via an anonymous factory
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, dependency1, dependency2) {
      return {
       'request': function(config) {
           // request transform
        },

        'response': function(response) {
           // response transform
        }
      };
    });

});
```

Interceptors are registered during the config phase of the AngularJS app. Their factory functions (either named or anonymous) are invoked during the `$get` phase of the `$http` service.

For more information, see [AngularJS $http Service API Reference - Interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors)

Comment: Thank you,  I just got my first one up and running and I'm understanding better now